# What could be cultural artifacts that represent each world biome?

Tags: culture, earth

**I want to identify significant cultural (contemporary) man-made artifacts that are native to each of the world's 6 biomes.** These include: 1. Desert Biome 2. Grassland Biome 3. Rain Forest Biome 4. Deciduous Forest Biome 5. Taiga Biome 6. Tundra Biome.
When I say native, I mean the artifacts reflect the indigenous plants, animals, or other parts of the ecosystem, as well as the regional culture. For example, the totem poles of North America were constructed of wood from the forest area. The totem poles connect the land with the culture and are at the same time a significant representation of cultural heritage. This example is one from history, but I am looking for *contemporary* artifacts which can be much more difficult to decide on.

Does anyone have suggestions or references on one or more of these biomes and their respective cultural artifacts? I understand the biomes are broad and contain many cultures, but I am looking at this from the perspective of: how similarly and differently does each biome influence man-made objects?

Wouldn't it be cool to see 6 rugs from 6 different biomes side-by-side? How similar and different are they in their weave, material, coloring, use, etc? I'm interested in comparing and contrasting— while celebrating diversity and our reliance on earth. Anyway, I'm basically looking for suggestions to consider besides rugs. Suggestions on artifacts that are visually interesting and a wide variety of people would stop to look/ponder over.

Anything helps! Thanks :)

Comment: Are you essentially looking for souvenirs?

Comment: I think body decorations would be an interesting possibility. Jewelry, headdress, piercings, etc

Comment: I'm tempted to close this question for 'too broad'. Asking for 6 biomes should be split to different questions

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, M.Rose. Actually I think you've answered your own question in the question itself. Namely, "the artifacts reflect the indigenous plants, animals, or other parts of the ecosystem, as well as the regional culture." It is a matter of choosing which ecological or cultural item would be symbolized on their artefacts. Have fun here!

Comment: This question is almost certainly going to be closed as opinion based. I suggest you just read about the cultures as most books will mention something of significance/cultural value.

Comment: Regional flora is not just influenced by biomes and current climate conditions, but also by geological history of plate tectonics.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm a North American, I'll list cultural artifacts that match up with North America.

1. Desert. To show the type of biome and culture, a pueblo would work.
2. Grasslands. Teepee.
3. Rain Forest. Mayan Pyramid. Central America is still part of North America!
4. Temperate Forest. Monk's Mound in its glory days.(Remnant of most advanced civilization that was located within the current boundaries of the USA)
5. Taiga. A bit trickier, but you can always go with a First Nations longhouse.
6. Tundra. Even trickier, but for the same sense of scale, you could have a village worth's of igloos.